# postgres query to get functions from user-installed modules

Tags: postgresql

I am currently working with a postgres 11.5 database. I am using this query to list all user-installed modules:

```
SELECT extname AS extension_name, nspname AS schema_name
FROM pg_extension
JOIN pg_namespace ON pg_extension.extnamespace = pg_namespace.oid
WHERE nspname <> 'pg_catalog' AND nspname <> 'information_schema';
```

which sorta works.

Since some of the modules create their functions in the public schema, its a bit of a mess. What I am trying to do is list all the functions from these user-installed modules. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You can find the solution here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/255412/how-to-select-functions-that-belong-in-a-given-extension-in-postgresql